# Javascript OOP - Accessing method from prototype setter

Tags: javascript, oop

I Get an 'undefined' error when trying to run the following code. It happens on the line `this.xPositionForPageAtIndex(selectedPageNumber)`. When I try to log `this` all of the instance properties are there, except the function.

```
function Gallery(div) {
    this.count = 5;
    this.pageWidth = 500;
    this.selectedPage = 1;

    this.xPositionForPageAtIndex = function(pageIndex) {
        if (pageIndex < 1 || pageIndex > this.count) {
            return 0.0;
        }

        return (pageIndex - 1) * this.pageWidth;
    }
}

Gallery.prototype = {
    set selectedPage(selectedPageNumber) {
        var page = this.pages[((selectedPageNumber) + 1)];

        if (!page.classList.contains("animate")) {
            page.classList.add("animate");
        }

        if (!page.classList.contains("final")) {
            page.classList.add("final");
        }

        console.log(this);

        this.binder.setAttribute("-webkit-transform", "translateX(" -this.xPositionForPageAtIndex(selectedPageNumber) + "px)");

        this.selectedPage = page;
    }
}
```

I am a little new to Javascript OOP, but I don't think I really know enough terminology to be able to properly research this answer.

Comment: Is this a special kind of JS??

Comment: Its javascript object oriented programming

Comment: There should be a `+` before `this.xPosition...` on the line where you set the webkit attribute

Comment: I want to scroll the gallery from left to right, in order to do that the x position has to be negative.

Comment: Then you should have `+ -this.xPosition...`

Comment: anyone reading this who, like me, was puzzled by `set` might want to have a look at this http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/

Comment: @David ok, I understand what you mean now

Comment: When I test for page to exist and comment out `this.binder.setAttribute...` in the log object the function is there. However uncommenting that line (and still checking page exists) doesn't show the function in the logged object

Comment: OK, so it turns out the order of `this.xPositionForPageAtIndex` should be before `this.selectedPage`. Not sure what the first error was, maybe the concatenation problem. Thanks all anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concat issue

On the line you said you were having trouble with had a minus instead of a plus:

```
"translateX(" -this.xPositionForPageAtIndex(selectedPageNumber)
```

should be

```
"translateX("  + this.xPositionForPageAtIndex(selectedPageNumber)
```

### Optimize by putting public methods in the prototype

Also, it may be a good idea to put `xPositionForPageAtIndex` in the prototype as well, since it doesn't rely on any private fields.  Any public function(which means it relies on no private fields) can go into the prototype.  That way, there won't be a copy of the function for each instance of the object you're creating.

Based on your code, I don't think you'll have enough `Gallery` instances for this to be a problem, but it's good practice nonetheless.

On the other hand, if your function relies on some sort of private field, that means it's a privileged function, and it cannot go into the prototype.  Something like this:

```
function Gallery(someParam){
    //this is a private variable
    var hiddenVar = someParam + "bar";

    // this is a privileged method: publicly accessible, but
    // can "see" private variables
    this.showHidden = function() {
        return hiddenVar
    };      
};
var gal = new Gallery("foo");
gal.hiddenVar; // undefined
gal.showHidden(); // "foobar"
```

### Unintended infinite recursion

A bigger problem is the following line:

```
this.selectedPage = page;
```

that line is within the setter for the property `selectedPage`.

That line makes `selectedPage` recursively call itself, and can only end in a `RangeError`.

Writing it in terms of functions makes it a little more clear, so here is what's happening:

```
var a = {
    foo: function(param){
        // do some stuff
        this.foo(4);
    }
};
```

calling `a.foo(2)` will result in a `RangeError`.

It's hidden a bit, because of the way ES5 setters work.  Here's what that would look like using setters:

```
var a = {
    set foo(){
        // do some stuff
        this.foo = 3;
    }
};
```

calling `a.foo = 2`  will result in a `RangeError` because the setter function is being called recursively.

Hope that helps a bit.  If you haven't checked out Douglas Crockford yet, youtube him.  There are some good lectures that may help you out quite a bit.